# React Redux error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

Previously, I made a lot of successfuly calls to another APIs in my backend (springboot), using this same way, but creating a new call I received the error: "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions".
I tried a lot of answers of other people but no luck. Does anyone knows waht happens? thanks a lot in advance.

### Action:

```
export function getAllValuesAction(listId, player) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch( getAllValues() );
        try {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(token) {
                tokenAuth(token);
            }
            const answer = await clientAxios.post(`/pays/sum/player/${listId}`, player);
            dispatch( obtenerSumaPagosJugListaExito(answer.data) );
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch( getAllValuesError() );
        }
    }
}

const getAllValues = () => ({
    type: START_GETTING_VALUES,
    payload: true
});
const getAllValuesSuccess = sumaPago => ({
    type: GETTING_VALUES_SUCCESS,
    payload: answer
});
const getAllValuesError = sumaPago => ({
    type: GETTING_VALUES_ERROR
});
```

### The store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';
const store = createStore(
    reducer, 
    compose( applyMiddleware(thunk), 
        typeof window === 'object' &&
            typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined' ? 
                window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
    )
);
export default store;
```

### tokenAuth:

```
import clientAxios from './axios';
const tokenAuth = token => {
    if(token) {
          clienteAxios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    } else {
        delete clienteAxios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    }
}
export default tokenAuth;

const clientAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
});
export default clientAxios;
```

### Plus:

just if someone also knows (but at least I need to know just the first "react redux error" question):
when I use GET in the call I receive the error message without having response.
When I use POST (like example in "Controller" below), I receive first the response and then, the error message.

The springboot controller receiving the request:

```
@PostMapping("/pays/sum/player/{listId}")
public Double getSumPayPlayerList(@RequestHeader (name="Authorization") String token, @PathVariable long listId, @RequestBody Player player ) {...}
```

the Pay repository making the query to the database:

```
@Query("select SUM(g.import) from Pay g where g.listId=?1 and g.player=?2")
public Double sumPaysByPlayerList(Long listId, Player player);
```

Thanks !

Comment: In an `async` action, you are supposed to dispatch only once. But you are dispatching multiple actions there. You may consider splitting your `getAllValuesAction` into smaller, individual actions.

Comment: Thank you Skmak, I tried a lot of things as you say (like example below), but nothing seems to work:

Comment: export const getAllValuesAction = (listId, player) => {
 return async (dispatch) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if(token) { tokenAuth(token); }
  const answer = await clientAxios.post(/pagos/sum/jug/${listId}, player);
  const data = answer.data;
  dispatch ({
   type: GETTING_VALUES_SUCCESS,
   payload: data
  });
 }
}

Comment: Can you go ahead and upgrade to the latest version of Redux (4.1), or even better, switch to using Redux Toolkit's `configureStore`? Those won't immediately fix the issue, but they have improved error messages that will tell you _what_ is being passed to `dispatch` instead of a plain action.

Comment: Thank you markerikson, I think I already have that version, this is a short part of the package.json:
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",

Comment: You may have more than one version of Redux installed in the project, because 4.1.0 does _not_ have that exact error message any more. You may need to temporarily uninstall both `redux` and `react-redux`, then re-install them, to ensure there's only one copy of Redux installed.

Comment: Thank you again markerikson, after reserach I found the issue was because I was trying to populate that information inside a Modal. For some reason that situation generates some delay or desynchronization, so had to remove the modal and find another way to show the info.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was because I was trying to show that information inside a Modal. For some reason that situation generates some delay or desynchronization, so had to remove the modal and find another way to show the info. Thank you all for your help.